# Semantic UI model pop up on submit button

Tags: coffeescript, semantic-ui

I am trying to show up a model pop up on submit button. So when ever the submit button is clicked a model will show up with yes or no if no so it will dismiss the model and on yes it will submit the form!

By button and model code just have a header for now!

```
= f.submit 'Claim Job', class: "ui button primary job_claim" , onclick: 'Formspinner()'
 .ui.basic.modal
   .header wooo
```

my js is like simple:

```
window.Formspinner = ->
  $('.ui.basic.modal')
    .modal('show')
  return
```

using coffee script and slim html!
every time I click submit it submits the button but no model pop up!
want to use sementic-ui basic model which covers the whole screen!
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#basic

Comment: Press `F12`, select javascript console, submit that form and examine if there any error occurs.

Comment: is my code correct ?

Comment: will we use a link_to or button_to just to pop up the model ? which one ?

Comment: I'm not sure for the coffee script, such code has wrong indentation (`window.FormSpinner...` should be far left), but it may be only incorrectly pasted. You can also put `console.log("Formspinner invoked")` as the first command of this method to be sure it is run.

Comment: Also put this in single line: `$('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show')` to be coffeescript compliant.